# Windows XP SP3 TCP/IP No buffer space available

Tags: java, tcp, windows-xp

I need to create 1000 server sockets using Java. Somewhere between creating 600 and 700 sockets I'm getting this error:

> 05.04.2012 10:23:57 java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): listen at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.listen(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:127) at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59) at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52) at channelserver.NIOAppServer.initSelector(NIOAppServer.java:40) at channelserver.NIOAppServer.(NIOAppServer.java:27) at channelserver.NIOServer.main(NIOServer.java:433) at channelserver.NIOServer.main(NIOServer.java:438)

After that my computer reboots.
I've tried to edit the registry setting MaxUserPort = 65534 and MaxFreeTcbs = 2000, but it didn't help. 
What else can I do?
On http://serverfault.com someone told me that it may be related to JDBC, but I connect to DB only once. I use SQLite.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone would face this problem too.
Finally it seemed to me that it's just WinXP's problem. I've tried the same code with more RAM - results were the same. But when I've tried it on Win7, everything worked fine even with 1200 sockets. 
So, WinXP is just not suitable for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

on Windows XP have a limit on half-open connection to broke this rule you need to patch your tcpip.sys driver (but it's illigable) or using modern OS like Windows Vista/7 they haven't those limits.

Comment: I've read about it. I have current limit of 10 connections, but still able to handle about 300 working client-server connections. Don't think that's the cause